# Table head fixed position with horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need to create a horizontal scroll in table without having the `table thead` scroll,
the `table` `thead` should behave as fixed position, I cant use position: fixed; on the `<thead>` element because it will fix itself to the view port and not to the parent table.  This example is using `position:fixed` on `table thead` which fixes it to the top of the view port is there a way to do this without `position:fixed` ?

http://jsfiddle.net/E9mqk/1/

Comment: your fiddle works fine in chrome & FF & IE10. or I didn't understand the question correctly.

Comment: Usually thead is used to explain what's in that column all about. Making it fixed makes me wondering...

Comment: I updated the question, I can't use position:fixed because it fixed to the viewport rather than a parent container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
.table-fixed-header {
  position: absolute;
}
```

And `position: relative;` to parent.